# rubyにクエリを書き、持って来た文字列が条件検索に失敗する

Tags: ruby, mysql

rubyの文に直書きでクエリを書き、そのdbからもってきた文字列を条件にかけて検索しようとしているのですが、持って来ている値が同じに関わらず、if文で条件がtrueになりません。
下記のようなコードなのですが、どこがおかしいのかご教授いただけないでしょうか？
条件の部分は、一番下の行の箇所となります。

```
$db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'localhost', :user => 'root', :password => '')
usedb = $db.query(%q{use ruby_nfcpy;})

$select_column = $db.query(%q{select id, name, idm, status from users;})
$select_name = $db.query(%q{select name from users;})
$select_idm = $db.query(%q{select idm from users;})
$select_status = $db.query(%q{select status from users;})

loop do
  unlock_user_id = idm(nfc)

  p unlock_user_id
  $select_idm.each do |user|
    user.each do |key, value|
      p value.to_i
      if value == unlock_user_id
```

pメソッドで表示したクエリの文字列は以下のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 何か特殊文字が隠れているのかもしれませんね。一度、両方の文字列をBase64やAES、Hash関数等で別文字列にしても一致するか確認してみてください。

Comment: コードでは`to_i`したものを`p`で表示しているのに、その出力だとされているものは文字列になっています。コードと結果のどちらかまたは両方が実際とは異なっていませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p value.to_i` しているのに比較のときは`.to_i`していないのが気になります。
比較しているもの通しのクラスは同じでしょうか？

```
a = 1
b = "1"

p (a == b) #=> false
```

以下のように正しく比較できるように型を合わせてください。

```
a = 1
b = "1"

p (a == b.to_i) #=> true
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます
to_iメソッド使って両者の型を変更したらtrueで通りました。
以後気をつけたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 比較しているもの同士のクラスはNumericクラスだと思われます。sqlで呼ぶものが本当にNumericクラスかは微妙なんですが。。sqlの型はintegerでした